# Custom name for "404" page in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In my Phoenix app I have this:

```
defmodule MyAppWeb.ErrorView do

  # ...........

  def render("not_found1234.html", assigns) do
    # ...........

  end
```

How can I tell Phoenix that it should render "not_found1234.html" when a resource isn't getting found instead of "404.html"?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this, but imagine in your `ErrorView` module you can simply do something like:

```
def render("404.html", assigns) do
  render("not_found1234.html", assigns)
end
```

And creating a file in `lib/yourapp_web/templates/error` with the name `not_found1234.html.eex`

(if the logic that phoenix will precompile the files in the `error` dir and create a proper function to handle those names, as it does if you create a 404.html.eex, this should work)

https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/views.html#the-errorview

(if it works, it still doesn't mean that's a good idea, that depends on why you're doing it, and there are other ways in which you can have a template call, from inside itself, a helper render function that renders another template, etc, but the same applies)

Comment: Yes you can do this ^, especially if the goal is to simply change the name that is rendered per original post. Here's a tutorial on the customization process: https://elixircasts.io/custom-error-pages-in-phoenix

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do this instead of m3characters answer:

```
def render("404.html", assigns) do
   render_template("not_found1234.html", assigns)
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't. [source](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/errors.html#content)

> Phoenix will detect any 400 or 500 status level errors in our application and use the render/2 function in our ErrorView to render an appropriate error template. We get default implementations for 404 and 500 HTML errors, but we can add any clauses to render/2 that we might need. Any errors which don’t match an existing clause of render/2 will be caught by template_not_found/2.

You need to customize `MyApp.ErrorView`.

In general having multiple not found pages is not a good pattern, what you could do is extend the `404.html` view and pass more information to it, such as the resource type, resource id, url of the request...

Comment: **How can I tell Phoenix that it should render "not_found1234.html" when a resource isn't getting found instead of "404.html"?**

Comment: *you cant*. Elixir is a pattern matching language, meaning when Phoenix detects a 404 it calls render with "404.html" and it matches the function defined on `Hello.ErrorView`. You ARE using a framework, you have to play by the framework rules.

Comment: [here you can find more info on how to extend the error view](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/views.html#the-errorview)